# Generating Whatsapp password using Wart

Tags: api, passwords, whatsapp, password-recovery

I didn't find a single solution for my question.

How to generate whatsapp password.

I planned to create an app to send whatsapp message using C#.net.

1. Wart is not working. It is showing "Bad_Tokent".

any other way to generate the whatsapp password?

Answer (score 1):

Wart is outdated, Now WhatsApp has 2 step authentication process, which isn't possible using code.

Answer (score 0):

It no longer supports virtual phone numbers, which you apparantly have.